# What actually reuseaddr option does in socat?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, udp, socat

I'm reading the doc about socat [here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/getting-started-socat) and [here](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLE_OPTION_REUSEADDR).

The example `socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:3334,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:/tmp/test.log,creat,append` works well with and without option `reuseaddr`.

What does the `reuseaddr` do?
Why above example works well with and without the `reuseaddr`?
In which cases the `reuseaddr` is really needed?

Comment: `strace -f socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:3334,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:/dev/null 2>&1 | grep REUSEADDR` displays: `setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0`. Socat version 1.7.4.4

Comment: @dimich indeed. I checked again and can see option `SO_REUSEADDR` on the `setsockopt`. Modified my question accordingly your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reuseaddr` allows to bind to address which is in `TIME_WAIT` state, e.g. after server is killed while client is connected.

Without `reuseaddr`, server side:

```
$ socat -u TCP-LISTEN:3334,fork -
```

Client:

```
$ socat -u TCP-CONNECT:localhost:3334 -
```

Back to server:

```
^C
$ netstat -nta | grep 3334
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3334          127.0.0.1:37578         TIME_WAIT  
$
$ socat -u TCP-LISTEN:3334,fork -
2023/01/14 16:44:19 socat[84239] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:3334}, 16): Address already in use
```

With `reuseaddr` (before run wait until `TIME_WAIT` state passed away, or use different port number):

```bash
$ socat -u TCP-LISTEN:3334,fork,reuseaddr -
```

Client:

```
$ socat -u TCP-CONNECT:localhost:3334 -
```

Back to server:

```
^C
$ netstat -nta | grep 3334
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3334          127.0.0.1:35168         TIME_WAIT  
$ socat -u TCP-LISTEN:3334,fork,reuseaddr -
```

^^^ No error.

Note `reuseaddr` should be applied to both initial and subsequent sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the important part: http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLE_OPTION_REUSEADDR

> due to reuseaddr, it allows immediate restart after master process's termination, even if some child sockets are not completely shut down

So the difference should only be visible *if some child sockets are not completely shut down*.

I've tried your example and could see (with lsof) the reuseaddr option on the socket activated

```
socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:3334,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:/tmp/test.log,creat,append
...
lsof -nP -i -sTCP:LISTEN -T f | grep 3334
socat     46095 userabc    5u  IPv4 0x59cfcb9c717622ef      0t0  TCP *:3334 (SO=ACCEPTCONN,PQLEN=0,QLEN=0,QLIM=5,RCVBUF=1048576,REUSEADDR,SNDBUF=1048576 TF=MSS=512,UNKNOWN=0xa0)
```

```
socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:3334,fork OPEN:/tmp/test.log,creat,append
...
lsof -nP -i -sTCP:LISTEN -T f | grep 3334
socat     46375 userabc    5u  IPv4 0x59cfcb9c6f806e0f      0t0  TCP *:3334 (SO=ACCEPTCONN,PQLEN=0,QLEN=0,QLIM=5,RCVBUF=1048576,SNDBUF=1048576 TF=MSS=512,UNKNOWN=0xa0)
```

Comment: how to model a situation when some child sockets are not completely shut down? I also can see reuseaddr option on socket. Have modified my question accordingly.